# How to run maven command using groovy script

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using maven verison 3.3.9 on linux-version: "4.4.0-43-generic". For somehow i can run the maven command using this way on console:

```
 mvn -pl '!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed' -P compileWithGradle,nightly,flex-debug clear
```

double quotes inside the single quote i dont know the reason but it is working this way on console. I have a jenkins pipline in which i want to use this command but it is not working eiter i use:

```
sh ''' mvn -pl '"!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed"' -P compileWithGradle,nightly,flex-debug clear '''
```

OR use :

```
 sh """ mvn -pl '"!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed"' -P compileWithGradle,nightly,flex-debug clear """
```

result will be given in a `"!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed" OR  '!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed'`

Can someone tell me a proper way to use in jenkins script or inside a maven goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sh 'mvn -pl "!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed" -P compileWithGradle,nightly,flex-debug clear'
```

It should work.

Comment: Not working, i already tried this. actually on jenkin console it showing like this: mvn -pl "com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed" -P compileWithGradle,nightly,flex-debug clear

Comment: Are you using jenkins scripted pipeline? Try just `sh 'mvn -pl "!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools,!com.mycom.hpe:testbed" -P compileWithGradle,nightly,flex-debug clear'`. it should work without additional single quotes.

Comment: Yes i am using pipeline and already tried this but it is not working like this way.

Comment: I have change maven to 3.1.1 and updated a question which need a single quote.

Comment: @user565 what do you mean by "not work"? Can you put  logs?

Answer (score 0):

If bash shell is used you have to escape !. with a backslash `\`. This works.

```
mvn -pl \!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools
```

Ah , but this is not working in Jenkins groovy code.(2 backslashes)

```
sh "mvn  -pl \\!com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools"
```

This does not work in jenkins+ groovy + maven

MVN error: Could not find the selected project in the reactor: !com.mycom.hp.comp:zonegtools

Answer (score 0):

I can run mvn command in the groovy file like this. Could you try this?

```
run('mvn install:install-file -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -DgroupId=com.sample-DartifactId=sample -Dversion=2.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=src/main/lib/sample-2.1.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true')
```

Comment: what is the run command in Groovy?  How did you make the maven command run from Groovy script?